# How to replace the word in the string by using replace in Android?

Tags: android, string

I want to replace one word in the String by using `substring`. But it seen didn't work.

for example: The `string is 0000` , and I want to **replace the first word from 0 to 1.**
It should be `1000`. but it doesn't.

The code is like the following

```
String WorkStatus = "0000";
if(WorkStatus.substring(0, 1).matches("0"))
{
    WorkStatus.substring(0, 1).replace("0", "1");
    Log.d(TAG, "WorkStatus.substring(0, 1) = " + WorkStatus.substring(0, 1) + "\n");
    Log.d(TAG, "WorkStatus = " + WorkStatus + "\n");
}
```

**It didn't work , the string always show 0000. And what I want is "1000"**

**Do I missing something ?**

Comment: String.replace() returns a new String object, it doesn't modify the original.

Comment: You should start variable names with a lowercase letter. See [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), page 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
String WorkStatus = "0000";
//You use matches, while you might as well use equals
if (WorkStatus.substring(0, 1).equals("0")) { 
    //reassign workstatus to workstatus where the first entry is a '1' + the last three chars "000"
    WorkStatus = WorkStatus.substring(0, 1).replace("0", "1") + WorkStatus.substring(1, WorkStatus.length()); 
    Log.d(TAG, "WorkStatus.substring(0, 1) = " + WorkStatus.substring(0, 1) + "\n");
    Log.d(TAG, "WorkStatus = " + WorkStatus + "\n");
}
```

You didnt assign the modified string to WorkStatus

Another possibility is converting the string to a `char[]` and replacing the index, instead of working with substrings.

```
String WorkStatus = "0000";
char[] chars = WorkStatus.toCharArray();
if (chars[0] == '0') {
    chars[0] = '1';
    WorkStatus = new String(chars);
}
```

If you want other chars to become 1 instead of zero, alter the `chars[0]` into `chars[index]`, where index is the index you want to change from 0 to 1

Or, even easier, use a `StringBuilder`:

```
int yourIndex = 2; //your index which you want to check for 0 and change to 1
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("0000");
if (sb.charAt(yourIndex) == '0')
    sb.setCharAt(yourIndex, '1');
WorkStatus = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I have try , but the `WorkStatus`  only show "1" , not "1000".

Comment: it returns `1`, not `1000`

Comment: Yes , but what I want is 1000

Comment: But it seem work for only first. If I want to replace the second word. Shoud I use the following code ?
`WorkStatus.substring(0, 1) + WorkStatus.substring(1, 2).replace("0", "1") + WorkStatus.substring(2, WorkStatus.length());`

Comment: @Martin Your requirement broadens, it seems. I answered your question, but now you generalize your question. However, if you want to change an index of the string, use the second approach, where you alter the `chars` index which you modify.

Answer (score 1):

method replace has a **return value** of the string after replaced
you shuold resign the result to the String

> WorkStatus=WorkStatus.substring(0, 1).replace("0", "1")+ WorkStatus.substring(1, WorkStatus.length();

Comment: I have try , but the `WorkStatus`  only show "1" , not "1000".

Comment: because you use the method substring
this method  reture a new string 
in your case '0'

Comment: So...How to replace the only one word in the string ?

Comment: you just wanna replace the first letter of the string?

Answer (score 0):

`WorkStatus.substring(0, 1).replace("0", "1");` returns `1`, you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`.

My solution:

```
StringBuilder WorkStatus = new StringBuilder("0000");
int pos = WorkStatus.indexOf("0", 0);
if (pos != -1) {
    WorkStatus.replace(pos, pos + 1, "1");
}
System.out.print(WorkStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you asign it to a new variable like the below code, you can get what you needed.

```
String newWorkStatus=WorkStatus.substring(0, 1).replace("0", "1")+WorkStatus.substring(1);
                  Log.d("LOG", "WorkStatus.substring(0, 1) = " + WorkStatus.substring(0, 1) + "\n");
                  Log.d("LOG", "WorkStatus = " + WorkStatus + "\n");
                  Log.d("LOG", "New WorkStatus = " + newWorkStatus + "\n");
```